# Ubuntu: Network connection seems to fail after some time

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, file-transfer, samba

I just bought a Shuttle XS-35 barebone mini-PC and put a 1 TB WD hard drive and 2 Gigs of RAM into it and installed Ubuntu onto it. The machine will post as a media server (streaming videos to my PS3) and as a webserver for some small private projects.

Now I wanted to copy my videos from my Windows 7 machine to the Ubuntu machine and therefore created a Samba share on the Ubuntu machine. I tried copying the files with the standard Windows copy function and with SyncToy but after some time (sometimes 5 copied files, sometimes 120 copied files) the Samba share just disappears. When that happens I can't reach the internet from the Ubuntu machine although the network connection still seems to be fine (IP still there etc.).

Between the machines lies a LinkSys router. When I try to ping my router (after the connection doesn't work anymore) from the Ubuntu machine only a very small subset of the packages actually get there (something around 20%). When I restart the Ubuntu machine everything seems to work normal again.

I have no idea where the problem lies here. Does anybody have a clue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How old is your Linksys router, can you access the internet reliably using the Ubuntu box? I used to have problems with IPV6 not being properly supported on my router but that was around about Ubuntu 7-ish. If you know how (sorry but I don't recall how I did it, try Google) try disabling IPV6 so your Linux box is forced to use IPV4.

Comment: The Linksys router is relatively new GBit-router. I disabled IPv6 by default.

Comment: And yes the connection is reliable until it stops working as described in my question.